# How to make a drawing program

Tags: iphone, drawing

I'm not expecting a very detailed answer here but just to be pointed in the right direction.

Let's say i wanted to make a drawing program like microsoft paint or the app draw something, how can i do this?

Do I basicly set colors on pixels and nearby pixels (for thickness) when I hover and click with the mouse?

I'm planning to make an app that requires the users to draw stuff in a simple manner, so any suggestions would be much appriciated :)

Best of regards,
Alexander

Comment: You can try cocos2d : http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this demo for your application

http://code4app.net/ios/Paint-Pad/4fcf74876803faec66000000

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/smooth-line-view

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/acedrawingview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mgdrawingslate

it may help you.

Answer (score 2):

`UIBezierPath` is the good option for drawing the lines on your `UIView`.For Drawing you need a custom View You can't draw on a UIViewController.

And use touch delegate methods for drawing lines.

declare an `UIBezierPath *bezierPath;` in .h file

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        bezierPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 5.0;

        UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        [bezierPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
     }
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

`setNeedsDisplay` will call your `drawRect:` method.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
  [bezierPath stroke];
    }
```

And you can change Storke color using `setStroke:` property.For complete idea gone through [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.
Hope this help's you